# Появление/исчезновение кнопки для скрола вниз если div скролится

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Проблема в том, что когда div прокручивается все нормально работает, но когда div не прокручивается, то все равно появляется кнопка скрола вниз.

```js
$('.box').append('<div class="scroll_bottom">vniz</div>');

$('.scroll_bottom').click(function(event) {   
    
    $(this).parent('.box').animate({
      scrollTop:$(".box")[0].scrollHeight
    }, 500, 'swing');

});
```

```css
.box{
  height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width:150px;
  position:relative;
}
.scroll_bottom{
   
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right:20px;
    bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <h3>Здесь он должен быть</h3>
  <ul>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>

  </ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <h3>Здесь он должен исчезнуть</h3>
  <ul>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>


  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вы же всем блокам box добавляете, без проверки
добавил блок box_content - так лучше высоту сравнивать

```js
//$('.box').append('<div class="scroll_bottom">vniz</div>');
var $box = $('.box');
function add_button_down() {
  $box.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('.scroll_bottom').detach();  // это нужно если будете использовать resize (если будут длинный текст, он может при изменении ширины экрана, падать на вторую строку)
    // сравниваем высоту главного блока (box)  с его высотой контента (box_content)
    if($this.outerHeight(true) < $this.children('.box_content').outerHeight(true)){
      $this.append('<div class="scroll_bottom">vniz</div>');
    }
  })
}
add_button_down()

// это нужно если будете использовать resize (если будут длинный текст, он может при изменении ширины экрана, падать на вторую строку)
// если считаете что в этом нет необходимости, ппрсот удалите resize
$(window).resize(function(){
  add_button_down()
})


$('.scroll_bottom').click(function(event) {   
    
    $(this).parent('.box').animate({
      scrollTop:$(".box")[0].scrollHeight
    }, 500, 'swing');

});
```

```css
.box{
  height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width:150px;
  position:relative;
}
.scroll_bottom{
   
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right:20px;
    bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="box_content">
    <h3>Здесь он должен быть</h3>
    <ul>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box_content">
    <h3>Здесь он должен исчезнуть</h3>
    <ul>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: заработало, Спасибо щас настрою все под свой код